# How to enable fractional scaling of GTK apps in KDE Plasma?

Tags: gtk, plasma, hdpi

While Plasma supports fractional scaling of Qt apps very well, the fractional scaling does not apply on GTK apps.

`GDK_SCALE=2 appname` can apply a scale factor 2, but it does not work for fractional scaling.

Is there any way to apply fractional scaling on GTK apps running on KDE Plasma? I am using Plasma 5.24.4 in Kubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question, but it may be useful to know for people in the same quandary that, as per the documentation, for now the GNOME/GTK scaling only supports scaling by integer numbers. So, `2` will work, but `1.5` won't.

> The global scale factor is now inherited by GTK apps when it’s an
> integer (Peter Eszlari, KDE Plasma 5.15.0)

Source: https://pointieststick.com/2018/10/21/this-week-in-usability-productivity-part-41/