# How to run apps in non-integer scaling

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am using Ubuntu 23.04 in KDE Plasma 5.27.4.
For desktop effects I am uing lightly. In lightly effects can't be applied on non-integer scaling, and without that effects are not visible.

How to use lightly in non-integer scaling?

Comment: So, what happens when you apply non integer scaling in display settings?

Comment: the program dont work

Comment: one of the ways i thought to solve it was by applying a custom resolution greater than my present resolution and then applying integer scailing but the process is quite difficult and i am new so i am finding more ways to solve this

Comment: Do Qt apps also don't work or is it only GTK apps?

Comment: Do both GTK (e.g. Firefox) and Qt apps (e.g. Dolphin) not work with fractional scaling or is it only GTK apps which don't work?

Comment: only some gtk apps are not working

Comment: This is a known bug. https://askubuntu.com/q/1389227/124466 There is no solution as of now.